# Nothing works to give write permissions to a folder (LAMP Lightsail)

Tags: linux, permissions, lamp

The error log that kicked off all this:

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/storage/logs/lumen-2023-06-30.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied\nThe exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/storage/logs/lumen-2023-06-30.log" could not be opened in append mode
```

Here is what I tried:

1. `sudo chmod +777 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs`
2. `sudo chmod +rwx /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs`

This did not solve the problem though. What else should I try?

Comment: Don't make a log file executable, or world-accessible. Check that the user running php has access to the directories, or configure a different log location.

Comment: Does the folder `/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/storage/logs/` exist on your system? If it exists, you need to make sure the user (that PHP is running as) has read, write and execute permissions for each intermediate folder.